# Insertion sort - Best/Average analysis

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

On referring Insertion sort [lecture](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/lecture/1hYlN/insertion-sort) taught by Sedgewick,

I learnt that,

> [Proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition): To sort a randomly-ordered array with distinct keys, insertion sort uses ~(1/4 )N^2 compares and ~(1/4 )N^2 exchanges on average.

I also learnt that,

> Best case - If the array is in ascending order, Insertion sort makes N-1 compares and zero exchanges

If I analyse the pseudo code,

```
int n = array.length;
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
  for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
    if(less(a[j], a[j-1]))
      swap(array, j, j-1);
    else
      break; // Is N^2/4 due to break statement?
  }
}
```

Question:

So,

Due to `break` statement to avoid further comparisons, insertion sort performs (N^2)/4 comparisons in average case and N-1 comparisons, in best case.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Ah a little more math is needed.

Did you Realize that number of swaps performed by insertion sort is exactly the number of inversions present in the input ?

Inversion: index pair (i,j) is an inversion if `i<j but a[i]>a[j]`.

```
So I(i,j) = 1 if (i,j) is inversion
          = 0 if (i,J) is not an inversion

Now you have to get the expectation of this to get the average case
E[I]= Sum(E[I_{i,j}) = Sum over i and j such that i<j [(1/2)]= 1/2*nC2=n*(n-1)/2*1/2~n^2/4

Why E[I_(i,j)]=1/2?
    E[I_(i,j)]=P(I_(i,j)=1)*I_(i,j)+P(I_(i,j)=0)*I_(i,j)
              = 1/2*1+1/2*0
              = 1/2
```

How many indices are there with i

```
1 2 3 4 .. n
For 1 there is 0 such indices
For 2 there is 1 such index [1]
For 3 there is 2 such index [1,2]
..
For n there is 1 such index [1,2,..n-1]
So total = 0+1+2..+n-1= n*(n-1)/2
```

Btw I guess you know this...but still.why 1+2+..n-1=n*(n-1)/2

```
Let the sum be S= 1+2+3+...+n-1
               S= n-1+n-2+....1
            -----------------------
              2*S= (n-1+1)+(n-2+2)...(1+n-1)
                 = n *n*n...n-1 times
                 = n*(n-1)
            So S = n*(n-1)/2
```

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in 4th line of your answer

Comment: @overexchange.: check the answer now.

Comment: Yes, In insertion sort, number of swaps performed is exactly the number of inversions unlike selection sort.

Comment: @overexchange.: yes and your best case logic is right.

Comment: Am trying to understand the layman approach, Am saying that `break` statement is differing the performances in average/worst case comparisons. But how much?(N^2)/4. To answer this we need Math, for sure

Comment: No it is just breaking whenever there is no inversion left in the subarray [1..i]. Now the number of comparisons can be different so instead of counting it we are considering the average cases over all the cases..That's what I explained. That's how break affects.

Comment: Can't we say: *Did you Realize that number of swaps & comparisons performed by insertion sort is exactly double the number of inversions present in the input ?*

Comment: @overexchange>; Not exactly equal. We are comparing the non-inversion elements once before we get out using break.

Comment: Got it. Thank you